# The method setOutline(Outline) is undefined for the type ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am receiving the following error in my code:

```
The method setOutline(Outline) is undefined for the type ImageButton
```

this occured at the following line:

```
 ib.setOutline(outline);
```

Below is am image displaying the errors:
[image]

Below is the dimens xml found under values:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

   <dimen name="fab_size">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="start_z">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="end_z">5dp</dimen>

    </resources>
```

Note:
`import android.graphics.Outline` was called

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? few details about context may help in getting better answer.

Comment: I am trying to get the Floating Action Button to work